# What is the difference between Salesforce and Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Can any one help me out? What is the difference between Salesforce1 and Salesforce? Can we create an app based on the requirement in Salesforce1 as we do in Salesforce? Salesforce1 is used in Mobile. Can any one brief me about Salesforce1? Any help is very much appreciated.

One of client is using the app exchange application which is a unmanaged package and would like to change the look and feel app with related to the Android device. Also would like to connect with the third party e-commerce site. Can it be done on Salesforce1 app with the SDK devices?

Answer (score 2):

"Salesforce" is usually used to talk about the "end user" parts of the Salesforce.com offer, like :

- Sales Cloud
- Service Cloud
- Marketing Cloud (Exact target)

Salesforce1 is the "platform" behind all these applications. Salesforce1 provide :
  - The Force.com framework for designing new applications
  - All the standard APIs
  - The mobile part of Salesforce
  - Heroku
  - Exact Target Fuel

I find this page useful to explain what is what to customers :
http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp

The tricky point is that the Salesforce mobile app is named Salesforce1 too, but this application is only an empty shell.

You can manage the contents and features of the mobile app directly from your usual Salesforce administration menu.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce is a Customer Relationship Management cloud software addresses all customer interface concerns, from sales and marketing to customer service, streamlining the enterprise resources.

Salesforce1 - Salesforce1 is the new social, mobile and cloud customer platform built to transform sales, service and marketing apps. Salesforce1 is the first CRM platform for developers, ISVs, end users, admins and customers moving to the new social, mobile and connected cloud.

Yes you can change the look and feel of the existing app to render that in Salesforce1. Also you can integrate to any site to get the information in to salesforce but as of now you can just get and see the data of the third party application (like SAP or any) inside salesforce. I.e. Changes will be reflected in one way i.e from external app to salesforce but not vice versa if you are using external objects ...see the links below for more info

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_data_source_define.htm&language=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_setup.htm&language=en_US